# Cómo enviar el token a web api desde un controlador MVC

Tags: asp.net, mvc, webapi

tengo una web api 2 desarrollada en C#, implemente la autenticación basada en token basándome en este ejemplo [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](http://www.mukeshkumar.net/articles/web-api/token-based-authentication-in-web-api)

he realizado pruebas y todo funciona bien en el login, pero el problema lo presenta a la hora de entrar a uno de los controladores que tengo en mi aplicación FrontEnd ya que al parecer no está enviando el token; el login lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/Token',
  method: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  data: {
    grant_type: 'password',
    username: $('#usr').val(),
    password: $('#pswd').val()
  },
  success: function(response) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.access_token);
    window.location.href = "/Home/Index";
  },
  error: function(jqXHR) {
    alert('Error', jqXHR.responseText);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

y el token lo envío de la siguiente manera:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/Employees',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken')
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var employeesData= JSON.stringify(data);
    window.location.href = "/Employees/Index";
  },
  error: function(jqXHR) {
    alert('Error', jqXHR.responseText);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

si lo hago de esa manera o con @Url.Action("Employees", "Index") me da error pero si elimino window.location.href = "/Employees/Index"; o @Url.Action("Employees", "Index") me responde el json con la información que requiero.

espero me explicara correctamente y que puedan ayudarme ya que soy novato en esto

saludos cordiales y de ante mano muchas gracias y feliz fin de semana

Comment: Hola. Qué mensaje de error te devuelve?

Comment: acceso denegado, por alguna razón no esta enviando el token